# is there a way to download all of the DNS records from PowerDNS?

Tags: dns

Is there a way to download all of the DNS records from PowerDNS?
I don't even know how the records are stored.

Comment: Not enough info, but if you have permission, you want to do a zone transfer. The named tool rndc, will accomplish this.

Comment: What I'm looking for is just a list of all the domains and their DNS entries that are on this server. The list is just to have a paper copy for reference. I don't want to change anything or move anything.

Comment: No chance......